# Raspberry Pi: SFTP to Root

Tags: raspberry-pi, sftp

I am trying to setup `SFTP` so that I have access to the root folder on my `Raspberry Pi 2.` Essentially I am trying to access / by default rather than ~/ when using `SFTP`. This way accessing my `Apache server` and associated files is much easier from the get go. I am looking for a simple way to achieve this.Please suggest.

Comment: have you tried `sftp ip_of_your_pi`? SFTP is subsystem of SSH and if it is running, there is probably available even SFTP.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working

```
sudo chown -R your-user-name /var/www/
```